# Regex expression symbol without space

Tags: regex

Here is my regex: `{{[^\{\s}]+\}}`

And my input is `{{test1}}{{test2}}{{test3}}`.

How can I get these 3 tests by array using regex expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use: `~\{\{([^}]+?)\}\}~`
and accessing array depends on your language!

[EDIT] add explanations

- `~`: delimiter
- `\{\{`, `\}\}~`: match characters literally. Should be
  escaped.
- `[^}]`: match anything inside `{{}}` until a `}`
- `+`: repeat
  pattern multiple times (for multiple characters)
- `?`: is for 'lazy'
  to match as few times as possible.
- `()`: is to capture

:)

[EDIT] add PHP code sample for matching illustration:

```
<?php
    $string= "{{test1}}{{test2}}{{test3}}";

    if (preg_match_all("~\{\{([^}]+?)\}\}~s", $string, $matches))
    {
        print_r(array($matches));
        // Do what you want
    }
    ?>
```

will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => {{test1}}
                    [1] => {{test2}}
                    [2] => {{test3}}
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test1
                    [1] => test2
                    [2] => test3
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test[0-9]+
```

This matches all occurences of `testX` where `X` is an integer of any size.

If you're trying to identify the braces instead, use this:

```
[{\}]
```

Answer (score 0):

C# uses Matches Method returns MatchCollection object.
Here is some codes,

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"{{[^{\s}]+}}");
        MatchCollection col = r.Matches("{{test1}}{{test2}}{{test3}}");
        string[] arr = null;
        if (col != null)
        {
            arr = new string[col.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = col[i].Value;
            }
        }
```